# Orange logistic regression doesen't return coefficients

Tags: python, logistic-regression, orange

from Orange docs (http://docs.orange.biolab.si/reference/rst/Orange.classification.logreg.html) I'm trying to replicate the results from this part of code:

import Orange

titanic = Orange.data.Table("titanic")
lr = Orange.classification.logreg.LogRegLearner(titanic)

## compute classification accuracy

correct = 0.0
for ex in titanic:
    if lr(ex) == ex.getclass():
        correct += 1
print "Classification accuracy:", correct / len(titanic)
Orange.classification.logreg.dump(lr)

and as result I only get "Classification accuracy" and nothing more. What I'm trying to get are regression coefficents, but the call Orange.classification.logreg.dump(lr) returns nothing.

Thanks, Peter

Comment: Could you try `print Orange.classification.logreg.dump(lr)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `print Orange.classification.logreg.dump(lr)` to print out the model (the example code in Orange documentation has since been fixed).

Note that you can get the coefficients in `lr.beta`.